# Database Proxy Node Failures During Writes

Tags: database, proxy, maxscale

In cases when a database proxy (e.g., maxscale) is present between the backend database and the client, what happens to writes if the proxy node itself fails. Specifically, I am interested in the following scenario:

1. Client issues a write command (assume that auto-commit is enabled).
2. Database proxy receives the write command from the client and sends it to the backend database.
3. Backend database receives the write command, performs the write, commits the transaction and sends the acknowledgement back to the proxy node.
4. The proxy node receives the acknowledgement. But, before the proxy node could send the acknowledgement back to the client, it dies.

In this scenario, the transaction has been committed and as far as the database is concerned, its client (i.e., the proxy node) has been informed. However, the actual client does not know whether the transaction was committed or not.

How do database proxies handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of MaxScale, when a client connection is abruptly closed the backend database connection is also closed. This makes the behavior similar to how the server would act without a proxy.